# In the Homeland Series Finale, Did Yevgeny Gromov know what Carrie was doing?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, homeland

In the last ever episode of the Showtime TV series, *Homeland*, the writers offer one last plot twist when it's revealed that Carrie Mattheson

> took Anna Pomerantseva's place as Saul Berenson's Russian Asset!

But what remians a bit unclear to me, is that Carrie's sort of lover, Yevgeny Gromov, a Russian GRU Officer who was first introduced in the previous season, is not a stupid man. Earlier in the episode, when he is forcing Carrie to either find and give up Saul's current asset or kill Saul, she admits to him, Saul's contingency plan, should something happen to Anna, which

> Carrie follows through on, despite no one expecting her to.

*So I was wondering, since he does seem to love Carrie, despite being on the other side, if the EPs or Writers ever revealed if Yevgeny knew what Carrie was doing or rather, if he was letting her do it?*

He seemed to have quite a lot of influence in the Russian intelligence community, despite what happened with his last girlfriend and I would think, if it wouldn't be for being on his arm, The Russians wouldn't just let Carrie settle in

> Moscow.

Comment: I just finished the series and have the exact same question. Also when they were working to get the helicopter blackbox she proposes to Gromov something about running their own independent network.

Comment: maybe that's part of the idea of the finale: for the viewers to wonder if gromov knows?

Comment: @BCLC could be! But I'm looking for proof from the EPs/Writers/Cast, which it doesn't look like I'm going to get! :)